# Tensorflow in r not found

Tags: r, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow in r with this code `install_tensorflow(conda_python_version = '3.8')`.
When calling `tf$constant('Hellow Tensorflow')`, I get this error:

```
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe
 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
```

However, I have the python.exe in the first location and have the library in `C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\r-reticulate\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\`. Why the tensorflow installation could not be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by typing `conda activate r-reticulate` to anaconda powershell while having the tensorflow installed in the r-reticulate environment.